# Get and show routing info for a known location [lat/long info] in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, arcgis

I am new to the arcgis framework for ios.I have tried out the routing sample provided by arcgis.But it work in a way that the `stops` are marked on the map ,then call the routing service retrive the data and add it to map.

But my purpose is a little different that I know the Latitude and Longitude information and I want to route from the current location to that point.Is it possible ? How can i achieve this?

I got a failure message when I tried .How can I achieve what I look for?

Comment: You should be able to do that.  What was the error?   How did you code the request?

Comment: @progrmr The real problem is how to define stops programatically because I dont find a way i can set the lat long info to the stop so thst it will work fine

Comment: Create an `AGSPoint` with your lat & long, use that to init your `AGSStopGraphic`, add that to your parameters and away you go...(?)

Comment: @Juffy can you add some sample code?I am trying to do the same but dont get it working

Comment: I deal mainly with the JS version of the API, so I don't have any iOS code handy. (hence the comment rather than answer) As @progrmr said, what error message are you getting? What code have you tried?

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate of your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17944002/1693173).  You can create AGSStopGraphics for routing without adding them to a map layer.  They don't have to be displayed.