# Creating an AGSStopGraphic,Routing ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, routes, arcgis

Trying to do routing with ARCGIS SDK for ios.I have a AGSPoint with me as

```
  AGSSpatialReference *sr = [AGSSpatialReference spatialReferenceWithWKID:102100];
  AGSPoint *myMarkerPoint =[AGSPoint pointWithX:-13626235.170442 
                                             y:4549170.396625 spatialReference:sr];
```

I have to make `AGSStopGraphic` with respect to this point ,How it can be done?This is something basic ,But don't know how to do it.

And how to do routing with this?Is there a better approch

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an `AGStopGraphic` using the `AGSPoint`.  Your `myMarkerPoint` is a geometry that defines the location.  Something like this:

```
AGSPictureMarkerSymbol* destSymbol  = [AGSPictureMarkerSymbol pictureMarkerSymbolWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RedPin.png"]];

AGSStopGraphic* stop = [AGSStopGraphic graphicWithGeometry:myMarkerPoint
                                                    symbol:destSymbol
                                                attributes:{@"Destination" : @"Name"}];
```

To do the routing request, you need to start with an `AGSRouteTaskParameters` object and add the stops to it (along with all the other parameters) using the `setStopsWithFeatures:` method.  Then using your `AGSRouteTask` object, call the method `solveWithParameters:` and pass it the route task parameters.

According to the [AGSRouteTask documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/ios/api-reference/interface_a_g_s_route_task.html) there is a [Routing sample](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=e4fa8dafbe83475882ac9c0fd0a075c7) app that you can look at.

Comment: Thank You,So where is the `AGSPoint` set up in that graphic?

Comment: its the parameter to `graphicWithGeometry:`, in my example above I used `myMarkerPoint` as the value.